# MS Project % Complete can only be 0 or 100%

Tags: ms-office, ms-project

I have a task in MS Project that I need to update and it only lets me enter in 0% or 100%. If I enter 50% it automatically returns to 0%. It has one predecessor that is complete and is an 'Automatically Scheduled Task'.

What could be preventing me from entering in something other thatn 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the task a Milestone? If so, then it will exhibit the behaviour you said because a milestone cannot be partially completed- It either is or it isn't!

It will be a milestone automatically if the duration is set to 0, or is you have manully declared it to be a milestone on the Advanced tab of the Task Information dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a resource that is available 0% of the time, it will act this way as well.  Delete the resource and it should allow you to set it to something other than zero or 100%.